# How to sort by fetched properties with distinct JPA Specifications

Tags: sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa, distinct, criteria-api

I use Spring Boot `1.5.3.RELEASE` and for me it's unclear how to sort by properties of nested objects with `distinct` and `Specifications` because of:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Spring Data JPA generates wrong query.

Let's see a little example:

#### Model

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_type_id")
    private VehicleType vehicleType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_brand_id")
    private VehicleBrand vehicleBrand;
}
```

We have `Vehicle` class with nested objects `VehicleType` and `VehicleBrand`.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle_brand")
public class VehicleBrand implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_model_id")
    private VehicleModel model;

}
```

Class `VehicleBrand` also contains `VehicleModel`.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle_model")
public class VehicleModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

#### Service

Now I want to create a query with JPA `Specifications` and some sorting by `"vehicleBrand.name"`:

```
public List<Vehicle> findAll() {
    Specification<Vehicle> spec = Specifications.where(
            (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
                return null;
            }
    );
    return vehicleRepository.findAll(spec, new Sort("vehicleBrand.name"));
}
```

Spring Data JPA generates following query:

```
select
    distinct vehicle0_.id as id1_0_,
    vehicle0_.gas_type as gas_type2_0_,
    vehicle0_.vehicle_brand_id as vehicle_4_0_,
    vehicle0_.vehicle_type_id as vehicle_5_0_,
    vehicle0_.year_of_issue as year_of_3_0_ 
from
    vehicle vehicle0_ 
left outer join
    vehicle_brand vehiclebra1_ 
        on vehicle0_.vehicle_brand_id=vehiclebra1_.id 
order by
    vehiclebra1_.name asc
```

And it fairly doesn't work because of:

> Order by expression "VEHICLEBRA1_.NAME" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement

To fix the issue we have to fetch `vehicleBrand` in our `Specification`:

```
public List<Vehicle> findAll() {
    Specification<Vehicle> spec = Specifications.where(
            (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
                root.fetch("vehicleBrand", JoinType.LEFT); //note that JoinType.INNER doesn't work in that case
                return null;
            }
    );
    return vehicleRepository.findAll(spec, new Sort("vehicleBrand.name"));
}
```

Spring Data JPA generates following query:

```
select
        distinct vehicle0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        vehiclebra1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        vehicle0_.gas_type as gas_type2_0_0_,
        vehicle0_.vehicle_brand_id as vehicle_4_0_0_,
        vehicle0_.vehicle_type_id as vehicle_5_0_0_,
        vehicle0_.year_of_issue as year_of_3_0_0_,
        vehiclebra1_.vehicle_model_id as vehicle_3_1_1_,
        vehiclebra1_.name as name2_1_1_ 
    from
        vehicle vehicle0_ 
    left outer join
        vehicle_brand vehiclebra1_ 
            on vehicle0_.vehicle_brand_id=vehiclebra1_.id 
    order by
        vehiclebra1_.name asc
```

And now it works because we see `vehiclebra1_.name` in the selection part.

#### Question

But what to do If I need to sort by `"vehicleBrand.model.name"`?
I make an additional `fetch`, but it doesn't work:

```
public List<Vehicle> findAll() {
    Specification<Vehicle> spec = Specifications.where(
            (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
                root.fetch("vehicleBrand", JoinType.LEFT).fetch("model", JoinType.LEFT);
                return null;
            }
    );
    return vehicleRepository.findAll(spec, new Sort("vehicleBrand.model.name"));
}
```

It generates following query:

```
select
        distinct vehicle0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        vehiclebra1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        vehiclemod2_.id as id1_2_2_,
        vehicle0_.gas_type as gas_type2_0_0_,
        vehicle0_.vehicle_brand_id as vehicle_4_0_0_,
        vehicle0_.vehicle_type_id as vehicle_5_0_0_,
        vehicle0_.year_of_issue as year_of_3_0_0_,
        vehiclebra1_.vehicle_model_id as vehicle_3_1_1_,
        vehiclebra1_.name as name2_1_1_,
        vehiclemod2_.name as name2_2_2_ 
    from
        vehicle vehicle0_ 
    left outer join
        vehicle_brand vehiclebra1_ 
            on vehicle0_.vehicle_brand_id=vehiclebra1_.id 
    left outer join
        vehicle_model vehiclemod2_ 
            on vehiclebra1_.vehicle_model_id=vehiclemod2_.id cross 
    join
        vehicle_model vehiclemod4_ 
    where
        vehiclebra1_.vehicle_model_id=vehiclemod4_.id 
    order by
        vehiclemod4_.name asc
```

And it doesn't work because of:

> Order by expression "VEHICLEMOD4_.NAME" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement

Take a look on how we select `vehiclemod2_.name` but make order by `vehiclemod4_.name`.

I've tried to make sorting in `Specification` directly but it also doesn't work:

```
Specification<Vehicle> spec = Specifications.where(
        (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
            root.fetch("vehicleBrand", JoinType.LEFT).fetch("model", JoinType.LEFT);
            criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.join("vehicleBrand", JoinType.LEFT).join("model", JoinType.LEFT).get("name")));
            return null;
        }
);
```

What should I do to make JPA generate right query so I could make a sorting by nested objects?
Does it make sense to upgrade version of Spring Boot from `1.5.3.RELEASE` to `2+`?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering why you need `.distinct(true)` in your query, since you're only joining along to-one associations. What happens if you remove it and use regular joins instead?

Comment: @crizzis,I have much more complicated model and queries via Specification, to simplify it I've made a little example. So in real case it's required

Comment: i get this issue, but need paging, so i lot of modification need to be done to be able to use orderBy this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little secret: you don't need to use the `Sort` parameter at all.

Just use `CriteriaQuery.orderBy`:

```
Specification<Vehicle> spec = Specifications.where(
            (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
                var model = root.fetch("vehicleBrand", JoinType.LEFT).fetch("model", JoinType.LEFT);
                criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(model.get("name"));
                return null;
            }
    );
    return vehicleRepository.findAll(spec));
```

The `Sort` parameter is likely what's adding the extra join in your scenario.

Comment: Mismatch types. `root.fetch(...)` returns `Fetch`, not `Join`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Changed to `var`, in any case, you should be able to call `.get()` on the result

Comment: If only I could, but with `Fetch` result I can only use `fetch(..)` method. There is no possibility to use `get(...)`

Comment: As a final attempt to make it work, is it castable to `Join<?>` at runtime?

Comment: Also see my comment under the question

Comment: yes It's castable to `Join` at runtime and It seems it works

Comment: Is there any possibility to make it with `Sort` somehow? Why does it make extra join?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, the sorting mechanism simply isn't clever enough, and so `"vehicleBrand.name"` simply translates to an implicit join