# Sort value and distinct in a criteria query don't add the field to the query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3.2, spring data jpa, oracle.

Entity structure class

```
@Entity
public Request{

    @Id
    private Long requestId;

    private String title;

    @OnetoOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
    private QueryLog query;

}

@Entity
public QueryLog{

    @Id
    private Long queryLogId;

    private LocalDate creationDate;
    private String type;

    ...
}
```

If i don't put value for the sort query generated is

```
select
   distinct r1_0.request_id,
   r1_0.title,
   lq1_0.query_log_id,
   lq1_0.type,
   lq1_0.creation_date
from request r1_0
join query_log lq1_0
    on lq1_0.query_log_id = r1_0.query_log_id
```

If put queryLog.creationDate via pageable, for the sort, Spring data add another join

```
select
   distinct r1_0.request_id,
   r1_0.title,
   lq1_0.query_log_id,
   lq1_0.type,
   lq1_0.creation_date
from request r1_0
join query_log lq1_0
    on lq1_0.query_log_id = r1_0.query_log_id
join query_log lq2_0
    on lq2_0.query_log_id = r1_0.query_log_id
order by
    lq2_0.creation_date
```

but don't put the field in the select... so query fail

It's seem sort field name have impact on the query. Spring data add join

Specification call

```
Page<Request> requestPage = requestRepository.findAll(requestSpecification.search(requestSearch), pageable);
```

In my specfication class

```
public class RequestSpecification{

    public Specification<Request> search(RequestSearch requestSearch){
        return (requestRoot, cq, cb) -> {

           cq.distinct(true);            

           Join<Request, QueryLog> queryLogJoin;
           ...

        };
    }


}
```

I saw a similar issue with an older version of spring boot, spring data jpa
[How to sort by fetched properties with distinct JPA Specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975704/how-to-sort-by-fetched-properties-with-distinct-jpa-specifications)

since, don't seem to have a fix to be able to use Pageable